# Cache whole result set or based on user?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web application i have statistics which shown for each user separately
ie. posts made , posts made today , articles started by and so on...

Each user has his own special statistics.

What is more flexible and "right" to work with one huge DataTable in Cache with whole data from all users and then loop thought DataTable to find certain user data or to cache each user ie. cacheObj + userID...

User can filter his own results by dates and types which is why i need flexible and reliable solution

thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to just cache each user's results in the Session State.  It's unique to each user.  When they log in/access it for the first time, calculate the results and store it there.  That way too, you don't have to cache all user's information in memory all the time.  You just have to store it for who is logged in at the moment.

Comment: there is too much of data for Session imho, this is why i'm trying to use Cache... Again i don't know what the difference between Session and Cache because both stored in memory. Session i usually store on other machine using OutOfProc mode.

So your advice is to save data for each user rather than all the data ?

Comment: The session state, like the application state except stored for each user.  I would store it for each user, so that way you don't have to pull all the information from the out of proc mode each time you want to access the data (assuming you are storing all the data in one data table).